# Error with ajax and zf2 controller action

Tags: ajax, zend-framework2

I was trying to use ajax to redirect to a controller action in zend framework 2 but the ajax is not responding rightly as well as I am not receiving the data alert.

Here is the ajax code:

```
$(".save_btn").click(function (){ //the class of submit button is save_btn
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/template/addtemplate',
    data : {'id':'test'},
    success : function(data,status)
    {
        alert(data.message);
    }
  });
});
```

this is my controller code:

```
public function addtemplateAction()
{
    $result = array('status' => 'error', 
                    'message' => 'There was some error. Try again.'
              );
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

        $data = $request->getPost();

        if(isset($data['id']) && !empty($data['id'])){

        return new JsonModel($result);

            $result['status'] = 'success';
            $result['message'] = 'We got the posted data successfully.';
        }
    }
    return new JsonModel($result);    
}
```

I have also added these particular things in my module.config.php file :

```
'strategies' => array (
               'ViewJsonStrategy'
                ),
```

I think the problem lies in $request->isXmlHttpRequest() which returns blank.

Any help will be accepted..

Answer (score 0):

Use any kind of developer tools. Chrome => f12 => Network tab and check your response